# VB.Net Regex - Put spaces after number

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string like `"7&9 Captial 06Actual 567"`.

I used the regex function:

`Regex.Replace("7&9 Captial 06Actual 567", "[^\d-](?=[\d-])", "$& ")`

Output - `"7& 9 Captial  06Actual  567"`

but I need the output like this - `"7&9 Captial  06 Actual 567"`

It has to put space after number, should not skip special character.

pls help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for: `(\d)([a-zA-Z])` 
and replace with: `$1 $2`

Updated according to comment below:

Search for: `(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)`
Replace with: `A single space`

This will add a space between digit and letter or between letter and digit.

*I don't know if VB supports [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*

If you want to deal with unicode characters, use:

Search for: `(?<=\p{N})(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{N})`
Replace with: `A single space`

Where `\p{L}` stands for any letter and `\p{N}` for any digit.

Comment: Sorry again, it didnt work for another string. example "Super56" -Regex not putting space.

Comment: @user3416431: You said in the question `It has to put space after number`, so this substitution adds space after digit, not before.

Comment: can you show me how the regex to support unicode ut8 chars that are non english. for example: "Nationalité".

Comment: @user3416431 don't forget to mark M42's answer as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @misterfrb - thank you it worked, can i extract numbers also..it will be very helpfull.